# Unable to load URL in DOMDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

I have the following URL :
http://localhost:8000/PHPTrialProject/showPlace.php?lat=28.6139391&lng=77.20902120000005

I have extracted the query string from this and stored in two PHP variables :

```
 $latitude=$_GET['lat'];
 $longitude=$_GET['lng'];
 echo("latitude is : ".$latitude);
 echo("longitude is : ".$longitude);
```

I then append them to my next URL and try to load it into DOMDocument. I tried two ways :

```
 $url="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=".$latitude."&lon=".$longitude;
 $xml3 = $url;
 $xmlDoc3 = new DOMDocument();
 $xmlDoc3->load($xml3);
```

and

```
 $xml3 = ("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=".$latitude."&lon=".$longitude);
 $xmlDoc3 = new DOMDocument();
 $xmlDoc3->load($xml3);
```

However, both of them give me the following error :

Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Start tag expected, '<' not found in http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=28.6139391&lon=77.20902120000005, line: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPTrialProject\showPlace.php on line 98

How do I resolve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you're just sending it the URL not the Page itself, use either [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) or [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and then send it to your DOM document.

E.G

```
 $xml = file_get_contents("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=".$latitude."&lon=".$longitude);

 $xmlDoc3 = new DOMDocument();
 $xmlDoc3->load($xml);
```